# how to enable location service from my aplication on WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, service, localization, location, geo

I'm writing an application for some Geolocalization.

How can i programmatically enable / disable location service from my application? like a settings page into my personal application ?

Comment: Have you looked at the GeoCoordinateWatcher class : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher.aspx

Comment: Yes thanks, but i can't find a property to set " enabled " or "disabled". "status" is only get.

Comment: That should not be possible, Windows Phone is very strict unlike Android and doesnt allow such things.

Comment: Ok thanks, and there is a possibility to "link" some button to the System settings interface ? or i can only print a message that indicate how to do to the user?

Comment: Im not sure but I looked into the Library with a Search and couldnt find anything. So my guess would be no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your application you should try and use the Location service (GeoCoordinateWatcher), you should then check the Permission property, if this is set to Denied then this means that the user has, externally to your application, disabled location services on their phone therefore this is all you need to be concerned with. You can display a friendly message telling the user that certain features within your application will not be available but you leave the decision, to enable location services, up to the user.

The following article details the watcher_StatusChanged event handler, which includes the above check :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431782%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

Comment: ok! thank you very much. so i will put a messagebox that  display the "error" message ^^.